# Polymorphism Conundrum

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Now, I appreciate this is actually an opinion based question, so I expect it to be closed, but hopefully not before a few answers appear.  The subject matter I'm dealing with is new to me, but also it is massive.  I could spend a year here and still only be chipping the tip of the iceberg, hence why I've got myself a little stuck.

So, I have the situation where I have three real world objects, let's call them HelloWorld, Foo and Bar. Bar has all the same properties as Foo EXCEPT for one.  This particular property is not valid for a Bar.  Instead, Bar has an additional property which is unique to that type.  So, in my head it makes sense for Bar to inherit Foo.  Now a HelloWorld can have a Foo OR a Bar depending on the circumstances and operations will proceed differently depending on which one it holds.

What I want to know is - does the example below hold water, or does it have a code smell like week old haddock left in the sun?!  If it does smell, what would be the 'right' way to go?  This is all new code - I'm not refactoring, so I have the ability to do it right the first time.

```
public class Foo
{
    // This property is valid for Foo AND Bar
    public int Property1 { get; set;}

    // This property is valid for Foo ONLY.
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    // This cannot exist in Bar - so always return null, don't allow it to be set.
    public new string Property2 => null;

    // Unique to Bar.
    public List<int> Property3 { get; set;}
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public Foo FooProperty { get; private set;}

    private HelloWorld()
    {
    }

    // Create a new object with the property as a Foo.
    public static HelloWorldWithFoo()
    {
        return new HelloWorld()
        {
            FooProperty = new Foo()
        };
    }

    // Create a new object with the property as a Bar.
    public static HelloWorldWithBar()
    {
        return new HelloWorld()
        {
            FooProperty = new Bar()
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok - so my 'generic' example maybe lacked the context needed - apologies.  Having taken onboard the comments etc, I've applied it like so - and used the real world types for clarity.

```
public class Slot
{
    public CardBase CardDetails { get; set; }

    private Slot()
    {
    }

    public static Slot CreateSlotWithCard()
    {
        return new Slot()
        {
            CardDetails = new Card()
        };
    }


    public static Slot CreateSlotWithCarrierCard()
    {
        return new Slot()
        {
            CardDetails = new CarrierCard()
        };
    }
}

public class CardBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime InstallationDate { get; set; }
    public HardwareType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Card : CardBase
{
    public List<int> Ports { get; set; }
}

public class CarrierCard : CardBase
{
    public List<Card> SubCards { get; set; }
}
```

Does this look a little more along the right lines??

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there's no inheritance in your code.

Comment: What prevents you from creating a base class which provides the common properties and let ```Foo``` and ```Bar``` inherit from it and add their respective special properties?

Comment: @Shawn, that's what I was going to say. The pattern the OP describes (Bar :  Foo) is wrong. And not implemented anyway.

Comment: This really depends on what you are trying to do - using `Foo/Bar` as your examples doesn't really tell us anything about the relationship between the two types. You might want an interface, you might want inheritance with a no-op, you might want an abstract base class. Do you have a real-world example of a solution you are trying to solve? Patterns are there to solve problems - starting with a pattern rather than a problem is usually a problem in itself.

Comment: @spodger you're right - it wasn't a very good example.  I should have just used the real world context.

Comment: That looks better but why are you wrapping the `Card` in a `Slot`?

Comment: @Shawn good idea.  Upvoted your comment.

Comment: @spodger well spotted.  Amended.  So a Slot contains a Card - the Card can either be a standard Card with Ethernet ports OR it can be a Carrier Card which extends the Slot to be able to take 2 Cards instead of one, therefore doubling the Port count.

Comment: @Bertie, fair enough. I had no idea what your design was.

Comment: @spodger yeah, my bad.  I tried to keep it simple and ended up making it look nothing like the real problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out this is an opinion based question, so I can give you my own opinion on the subject matter which I think most people agree with.

Choosing which type inherits from which other type should come from the concept model not their implementations. Therefore you shouldn't ask *if Foo has such property and Bar has such property which inherits which?*, but you should ask *is Foo essentially a kind of a Bar or the other way around?*. If neither are a kind of the other one then consider writing an **abstract base class** or an **interface** for both types.

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting a base class with the shared properties.  I did consider an interface, but it would have to expose properties I don't necessarily want to 'permanently' visible.

Answer (score 1):

> So, in my head it makes sense for Bar to inherit Foo...

I think this shouldn't be the case. I think you want them both to inherit from another common class to hold the stuff they *share*.
And let them keep the stuff that makes them *different* to themselves.

```
public class Common
{
    // This property is valid for Foo AND Bar
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Common
{
    // This property is valid for Foo ONLY.
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Common
{
    // This cannot and *hence will not* exist in Bar.
    // public new string Property2;

    // This property is valid for Bar ONLY.
    public List<int> Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense - daftly I hadn't considered using a common base type.  The subject matter is massive and I've spent so much time understanding how it all fits together that I've become a little unstuck in the code.